# Selecting rows if the value is in a range: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select a subset of the dataframe by choosing rows only if the Rank value is between 1 and 16 (including 1 and 16). I can achieve this with the following code:

```
ScimEn = ScimEn.loc[ScimEn["Rank"] < 16]
```

However, I prefer to use the range function to achieve this:

```
rankings = range(1,16)
ScimEn.loc[ScimEn["Rank"] in rankings]
```

However, with this code, I receive this error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Can someone help me with figuring out what is wrong with the second approach?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: `ScimEn.loc[ScimEn["Rank"].isin(rankings)]`

Comment: do you have any ideas why just `in` is not working?

Comment: What @jezrael said.

Comment: because `in` expects a scalar return value, instead it gets an array of boolean values so it doesn't know what a sensible return value should be because what if only 1 value is true for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 17 instead of 16 to get your desired condition.

```
rankings = range(1,17)
ScimEn.loc[ScimEn["Rank"].isin(rankings)]
```